# Referencing JSON data result from API Request - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'll start out by saying that I am a pretty new web developer, so I apologize if this is overly basic... I just couldn't find it anywhere on Google.  I'm receiving JSON data back from an API call to omdb, and I am unsure how to reference a line in the data  Specifically, I am trying to reference the Rotten Tomatoes Value, and this needs to be repeatable for any movie I search.  I started by storing the response in JSON and then working through each item I need:

```
var body = JSON.parse(body);
console.log("Title: " + body.Title);
console.log("Release Year: " + body.Year);
console.log("IMdB Rating: " + body.imdbRating);
console.log("Country: " + body.Country);
console.log("Language: " + body.Language);
console.log("Plot: " + body.Plot);
console.log("Actors: " + body.Actors);
console.log("Rotten Tomatoes Rating: " + body.Ratings.????RottenTomatoes???);
```

It's just the Rotten Tomatoes Value Line I can't figure out!  Everything else works. To clarify, this is just a JSON referencing issue I cannot figure out.

```
{
  "Title": "Anastasia",
  "Year": "1997",
  "Rated": "G",
  "Released": "21 Nov 1997",
  "Runtime": "94 min",
  "Genre": "Animation, Adventure, Drama",
  "Director": "Don Bluth, Gary Goldman",
  "Writer": "Susan Gauthier (screenplay), Bruce Graham (screenplay), Bob Tzudiker (screenplay), Noni White (screenplay), Eric Tuchman (animation adaptation)",
  "Actors": "Meg Ryan, John Cusack, Kelsey Grammer, Christopher Lloyd",
  "Plot": "The last surviving child of the Russian Royal Family joins two con men to reunite with her grandmother, the Dowager Empress, while the undead Rasputin seeks her death.",
  "Language": "English, Russian, French",
  "Country": "USA",
  "Awards": "Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 10 wins & 21 nominations.",
  "Poster": "https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BNGJiNWFlYTMtZTBiZi00ZTVmLWJmZmMtNzEzYzZjNzYzZmRmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTA4NzY1MzY@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Ratings": [
    {
      "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "Value": "7.1\/10"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value": "85%"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Metacritic",
      "Value": "59\/100"
    }
  ],
  "Metascore": "59",
  "imdbRating": "7.1",
  "imdbVotes": "94,074",
  "imdbID": "tt0118617",
  "Type": "movie",
  "DVD": "16 Nov 1999",
  "BoxOffice": "N\/A",
  "Production": "20th Century Fox",
  "Website": "N\/A",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rotten tomatoes value is in the 3rd element of the array. Array indexes start at 0. Therefore, what you need is `body.Ratings[2].Value`.

Comment: If you are unsure which index Rotten Tomatoes will occupy you can do `body.Rating.find((element) => element.Source === "RottenTomatoes")` which will look at each index and return the first one where Source === "RottenTomatoes"

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the `Ratings array` is unpredictable, use `filter` function as below.

```
    //If the order of the source array is unpredictable
    //use filter

    var rtValue = body.Ratings.filter(function(source) {
      return source.Source === "Rotten Tomatoes";
    }).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is an array inside an object. body.Ratings[0]. You are referencing the spot of an array. Definitely look into arrays.

```
 "Ratings": [ { "Source": "Internet Movie Database", "Value": "7.1/10" }, { "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes", "Value": "85%" }, { "Source": "Metacritic", "Value": "59/100" } ]
```

See the [ square brackets ] Each object inside {} can be referenced with an integer inside [0], [1] etc.
Look at some online tutorials. www.w3schools.com/js is a great place to start